# Multiple DTMF circuit interfaced to one microcontroller, will it work?

Tags: embedded, parallel, system

I already tested this circuit with only one modification, I changed the R2 to 300kOhms which worked in my case. 
[image: DTMF circuit]

I interfaced this circuit to a microcontroller where they shared a common ground. I successfully read the telephone number of the caller as shown in this figure. Apparently, I received the code number (10 2) and the 7 digit phone number. The frame was encapsulated with byte 0 and byte 15.

[image]
Now, I wanted to create a circuit that contains 3 channels for 3 different phone lines which are then to be interfaced into one microcontroller..

If I'm going to share a common ground for them all (3 DTMF circuits and microcontroller circuit), will it work?

On the sidenote, based on the datasheet, the circuit is in single-ended configuration.

EDIT: I added the entire circuit shown below.
[image]

Comment: Show all of your circuitry including 3x DTMF decoders, phone line interface connections and the MCU. Your question is nearly impossible to answer without this information.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, I just added the entire circuit.

Comment: OK good. Now we can see a lot more of what you are intending. It is probably best to have all three of the DTMF decoders hooked to separate I/O pins on the MCU like you show. However there is a reasonable way to save a total of 7 I/O pins. You would wire the Q1 -> Q4 outputs of all three decoder chips up together to a 4-bit bus that goes to a set of four pins on the MCU. Then three other individual I/O pins would connect from the MCU to the TOE pin of each individual decoder. The STD pins would also be individually connected to the MCU similar to the way it is showing now. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) The software in the MCU would initialize all three of the TOE pins low to shut off the Q1-4 outputs of each decoder. Then software would monitor for a signal detect on any one of the STD pins. If one is seen showing a high output indicating a detect then the software would momentarily drive the corresponding TOE pin high and then read in the code from that chip via the 4-bit input bus. After the code is read in the TOE pin goes back low via the software. The MCU then resumes monitoring the STD pins again. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above). This alternate scheme requires a total of 10 I/O pins at the MCU. This is in contrast to the 15 total I/Os showing in your schematic for a savings of 5 pins. (please ignore the prior comment that the scheme could save 7 pins).

Comment: I need to add that you will need to follow the comment I made under @DaveTweed

Comment: (continued from above) 's answer. To stop causing an imbalance to the phone lines you will have to eliminate the connection of each phone line to the GND. You could use a small signal transformer for each line but that would have to be connected with one side of its primary isolated with a capacitor to prevent DC current in the transformer. Alternately you could try splitting your tap impedance into two. Keep the circuit very similar as now but change your 100K resistors to 50K and then put 50K in (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) series with the phone line tap that connects into the GND. This is not ideal however because it interconnects phone lines with 100K ohms and this is may be a problem (test and see). On the other hand the MT8870 offers the ideal solution for this with its IN+ and IN- pins. Both sides if the line can be connected with capacitors (they need to be high voltage units by the way) and then series resistors to these pins. See the schematic here: http://www.electronics-lab.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/DTMF_Receiver_IC_MT8870_Tester.gif

Comment: For the 2nd solution, u suggest placing a resistor between a terminal of the phone line and the ground. And by doing this, the phone lines are not coupled together via the same ground? (Just verfying..) Looks like I'll be proceeding with using the differential configuration mode of MT8870 as an alternative to the transformer.

Comment: The differential solution is the best way actually. The idea I mentioned to put the resistor between the phone line return and the GND of the detector circuit is just a suggestion to try. It still ends up coupling two phone lines at 2X the series resistor which may be not acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can have three of your DTMF decoder circuits connected to your microcontroller.

However, even though the three telephone lines nominally share the same ground (somewhere), you should really treat them as "floating" with regard to your decoders, and use a transformer to couple the audio from each line to the corresponding decoder.

Comment: If I were to use differential input setup for the decoders, will it fulfill the same purpose?

Comment: No. A differential input is not the same thing as a floating input. The difference is in the range of common-mode signal that can be handled.

Comment: I see. So the goal is to isolate the phone line from the circuit so that they won't share the same ground? 

What would happen if I were not to treat them as floating and proceeded with the input signals sharing one common ground? Will the data collide since it is not assured that the phone lines are in-phase?

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. I can't comment on "data collisions" since you haven't told us exactly how you connected the decoder to the microcontroller. And I don't see how the "phase" of the phone line (whatever that means) is relevant at all.

Comment: I'm sorry. The digital outputs of a DTMF circuit are connected to the I/O pins of the microcontroller. They share a common ground.

Comment: I assume that if you have three DTMF decoders, each one would be attached to its own set of I/O pins. Why would anything "collide"?

Comment: I'm not sure though at my statement. Sorry, but I think there would be a problem if the 3 phone lines were to share a common ground. And this is where I hypothesized that there would be data collision.. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The decoder is already shown isolated in the schematic via a capacitor. So the need for transformers, as suggested by David Tweed, will depend entirely on how the other side of the phone line is attached into this circuit. If it is simply tied to the GND then transformers would be required. You do not want to inter-tie the commons of three phone lines. The reason being that phone lines are not single ended and trying to tie multiple lines together will introduce AC line frequency signal into all the lines as they become unbalanced.

Comment: Referring to the complete circuit, do I still need to add a transformer? Or will it work just like that?

Comment: @Xegara You need the transformers for the reasons people have already outlined: you can't treat the three phone lines as having the same ground.

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet for the MT8870D, the outputs Q1-Q4 of the DTMF decoder chip are normally tri-stated, so you can connect the leads from each of the MT8807D's together and feed them into four inputs of the microcontroller.

The outputs are then enabled as outputs by enabling the TOE lead, which you currently have connected to Vcc.  Instead, you want to connect it to an output of the microcontroller.  Since there are three decoders, you will need an enable output for each 
chip.

Since the outputs are normally tri-stated, how to determine when a tone is present?  That is the function of the Early Steering and Delayed Steering outputs of the decoder.  The Early Steering goes high when a tone has initially been detected by the decoder, and the Delay Steering goes high when the tone has been decoded and fed into the output latches.  You probably want to use the latter for enabling the tri-state outputs.  You will need three separate inputs on the microcontroller to handle this.

So you have a total of four inputs for the digit, three enable outputs and three steering inputs, for a total of ten, compared to the 12 inputs fpr the digits from three decoders, and three steering inputs for a total of 15 lines for your current circuit.

Adding an additional decoder costs one input and one output line line in my scheme, and five input lines for the original circuit.